# Error: Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am getting the above error and couldn't figure out how to solve it. I have an array of objects that contain a boolean value, and need to show a toggle for each of these boolean.

Below is the code.

```
class Item: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var label: String
    var isOn: Bool
}

class Service: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var items: [Item] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(())
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var service: Service

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(service.items, id: \.self) { (item: Binding<Item>) in
                Section(header: Text(item.label)) {  // Error: Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol'
                    Toggle(isOn: item.isOn) {
                        Text("isOn")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `@Published` property wrapper in your `Service` class, rather than `didChange`, and iterate over the indices of `service.items` like so:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var label: String
    var isOn: Bool {
        didSet {
            // Added to show that state is being modified
            print("\(label) just toggled")
        }
    }
}

class Service: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item]

    init() {
        self.items = [
            Item(id: "0", label: "Zero", isOn: false),
            Item(id: "1", label: "One", isOn: true),
            Item(id: "2", label: "Two", isOn: false)
        ]
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var service: Service

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(service.items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Section(header: Text(self.service.items[index].label)) {
                    Toggle(isOn: self.$service.items[index].isOn) {
                        Text("isOn")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

**Update: Why use indices?**

In this example, we need to get two things from each Item in the model:

1. The `String` value of the `label` property, to use in a Text view.
2. A `Binding<Bool>` from the `isOn` property, to use in a Toggle view.

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070552/3088606) where I explain Binding.)

We could get the label value by iterating over the items directly:

```
ForEach(service.items) { (item: Item) in
    Section(header: Text(item.label)) {
    ...
}
```

But the Item struct does not contain a binding. If you tried to reference `Toggle(isOn: item.$isOn)`, you'd get an error: "Value of type 'Item' has no member '$isOn'."

Instead, the Binding is provided at the top level by the @ObservedObject property wrapper, meaning the `$` has to come before `service`. But if we're starting from `service`, we'll need an index (and we cannot declare intermediate variables inside the ForEach struct, so we'll have to compute it inline):

```
ForEach(service.items) { (item: Item) in
    Section(header: Text(item.label)) {
        Toggle(isOn: self.$service.items[self.service.items.firstIndex(of: item)!].isOn) {
        // This computes the index       ^--------------------------------------^
            Text("isOn")
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and that comparison to find the index would mean Item has to conform to Equatable. And, most importantly, because we are looping over all items in the ForEach, and then again in the .firstIndex(of:), we have transformed our code from O(n) complexity to O(n^2), meaning it will run much more slowly when we have a large number of Items in the array.

So we just use the indices. Just for good measure,

```
ForEach(service.items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
```

is equivalent to

```
ForEach(0..<service.items.count, id: \.self) { index in
```

Comment: That's very interesting! Why does it work for indices and not for actual objects?

Comment: @user1366265 I added to my answer, explaining why its easiest to iterate over the indices. You *can* iterate over the items, it's just not fun. 