# Update computed property with state variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following scenario: I'm creating a `Form` where the user can input an amount in a `TextField`. Additionally the user can select a currency through a `Picker`. The amount is formatted with a `NumberFormatter` and I want to update the text whenever the user changes the currency.

```
@State private var currencyCode = "EUR"
```

That's the formatter:

```
private let currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    var formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.currencyCode = $currencyCode // something like this, but that's not working!
    return formatter
}()
```

The form looks like this:

```
Form {
    Section {
        TextField("Enter a description", text: $reason)
        TextField("Amount", value: $amount, formatter: currencyFormatter)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
    }

    Section {
        Picker(selection: $currencyCode, label: Text("Currency")) {
            ForEach(codes, id: \.self) { code in
                Text(code)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you're just wondering how to update the text upon selecting a currency from the picker?

Comment: Basically yes, however the text depends on the currency formatted. So the currency code of the formatted somehow needs to be changed from the picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove the `$`. `$currencyCode` gives you a `Binding<String>`, but you want the value, not the binding to the value. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070552/3088606) where I explain Binding.)

Second, you want to use a computed property, because your number formatter needs to change based on your selected `currencyCode`. Put this inside your view struct:

```
private var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
    return formatter
}
```

Comment: Alright, I understand! Thanks for your explanation. The `TextField` however always resets my input whenever I pick a new value from the `Picker`.

Comment: OK, so it works perfectly fine when I set a default value to `@State private var amount: Double = 0.0`. However if I make it optional the formatter does not work.

Comment: I assume you mean the formatter returns a blank string if amount is nil?

Comment: As soon as I make `@State var amount: Double?` and type in a value, it always gets reseted (blank textfield) once I select a different `Picker` value. Also the text does not get formatted as currency string.

Comment: Figured it out now, thanks for your help. I'm using a custom `@Binding` variable and set that as text for the `TextField`, this answer helped me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799456/swiftui-textfield-with-formatter-not-working