# SwiftUI: Safe subscript for binding array

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

We have the practice of using safe subscript when accessing any element in a collection. Below is the extension we have.

```
extension Collection {
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

But when I try to use this with a binding object, it gives me an error saying

> Extraneous argument label 'safe:' in subscript

Below is the problematic code

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var service: service

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(service.items.indices) { index in
                Toggle(isOn: self.$service.items[safe: index]?.isOn ?? false) {  // Error: Extraneous argument label 'safe:' in subscript
                    Text("isOn")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a “safe subscript” if you know that `index` is from `item.indices`?

Comment: I *assume* that the compiler error  is misleading, and the actual problem is that your safe subscript returns an *optional.*

Comment: Yes! That was an oversight on my part, but I still get the same error even after chaining. I edited the question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues:

1. **You don't need to** use `items[safe: index]`, because you are given only valid indices by `items.indices`. You will never have an index that is outsides the bounds of the array.
2. **You can't** use `items[safe: index]`, because self.$service.items is a `Binding<[Item]>`, which is not a Collection, so your extension to Collection doesn't apply.

Just remove the `safe:` and you're good to go.

See the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070916/3088606) for more detail.

Comment: I don't agree with point #1 because there are cases in which indices are invalid and will cause an index out of bounds crash which I'm facing right now, so there must be a way to use a safe subscript with a binding array.

Answer (score 1):

The diagnostic message is confusing, but the problem is that your subscript returns an optional, but you're treating it like a non-optional. You're going to have to handle the case where it returns nil.

Personally I think this approach is fighting the system. You'd be better off using `ForEach(service.items)`. Rather than "safe" subscripts, avoid subscripts entirely.

Comment: ForEach(service.items) did not work unfortunately and I had to use indices.

Comment: Yes! That was an oversight on my part, but I still get the same error even after chaining. I edited the question above.

Comment: In this case, you actually need to use subscripts, and its safe to do so. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070916/3088606